# ODM 8.8 how to add elements in array in BAL

Tags: java, ibm-odm

I want to know if there is any way to handle the array (adding the elements to specific index) in BAL without writing any java code or functions  in BOM. ?

Is any in build BAL constructors OR syantax that can help me to add elements in array at specific index. ?

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge, There is no such inbuilt vocabulary to modify the array or list in ODM Rules. One way to achieve it is by calling the methods from action rules or decision tables and write Java code in it as per our requirement.

Answer (score 0):

There is no support for directly manipulating arrays in the BAL. But such manipulation is not likely to be required when working at the business level. I would typically hide such technical details in the BOM or (preferably) the XOM, leaving the business rules free to focus on the business problem instead of the implementation details.